# $G'$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G=\langle K\rangle$ that contains $[K,K]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

I am a bit stuck with this problem. It seems like a sensible statement but I cannot prove it. What I have to prove is that if $G$ is generated by a generating set $K$ then $G' = [G,G]$ is the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $[K,K]$. I can see that the smallest normal subgroup of $G$ that contains $K$ is $\langle K \rangle$, i.e. $G$ itself. However, I am not sure this implies directly the result I am looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of $[K,K]$?

Comment: $[K,K] = \langle \{[x,y] : x,y \in K\} \rangle$. The group generated by all the commutators of the form $[x,y]$ where $x,y \in K$.

Comment: One way to prove this would be to realise that quotienting by the normal closure of $[K, K]$ forces the generators of the group to pairwise commute. This then forces every group element to pairwise commute as they are products of generators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N \unlhd G$ with $[K,K] \le N$. Then the images of any pair of elements of $K$ in $G/N$ commute with each other. But $G/N$ is generated by these images, so $G/N$ must be abelian, and hence $G' \le N$.

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense. I was a bit unsure at first but then I realised that it is very obvious that $[K,K] \leq G'$ and with your proof it is now clear that $G'$ must be minimal.